# transcribeCallback not sending request need php work around

Tags: php, curl, twilio

I am working on a transcription application and have everything working except that have noticed that twilio is not sending out transcribeCallback request using the following

```
<Record transcribe="true" transcribeCallback="sms.php?success=numero" action="adios.php" method="POST" maxLength="7"/>
```

but have noticed that "adios.php" is being requested so decided as a dirty fix, I would have php curl send out a POST request, but then noticed that $_SESSION['number']; is not being called by twilio server requests, but if I request "adios.php" via web browser everything works fine...

```
<?php
session_start();

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"number=".$_SESSION['number']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

after doing some research "nginx access.log" and getting some insight from twilio support it turns out that i needed to change my code around for everything to work. twilio was calling "transcribeCallback" correctly... my bad...

```
10.210.106.176 - - [29/Oct/2013:05:57:23 +0000] "POST /twilio/sms/sms.php?number='5555551212 HTTP/1.1" 200 45 "-" "TwilioProxy/1.1"
```